# Draw with mouse and save the drawn region as separate image

Tags: vb.net, winforms

Please see following picture:

[background picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M3pcj.jpg)

The image Abc in red color is the background picture, maybe preloaded on some control, for example a picturebox control.

The black rectangle region is drawn using mouse. What I want to achieve is to copy out the drawn region as separate image.

My goal is the winform will display each mouse drawing stroke until there is a closed region being formed or enclosed. That means a closing contact point need to be tracked.

Could you advise me on the key classes that I need to look into?

Comment: You expect it to be drawn in one stroke, or could I make four independent lines to form a box?

Comment: It has to be free style (any strokes) until a closed region is formed. That way is closest to real usage.

Comment: Then you need an algorithm to determine full 360 degree closure, not just the end point.  That might be difficult.

Comment: Perhaps this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24441911/how-can-i-tell-if-a-list-of-3-or-more-line-segments-form-a-closed-region-in-3d#24441995

Comment: My idea is if there are two same coordinates being registered then it's closing point.